# Storing a Sum in a Variable

Tags: excel, vba

The code I have is below:

```
For i = 1 To 15
X = Worksheets("Total Sales").Cells(i, 2)
sumTotSales = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(functionA(X))

Next i
```

The funciton loops though all cells 1-15 in column 2 and feeds the values into "functionA" which multiplies it by a percent.  I want to save the sum of this in the variable sumTotSales.  However, it will only save the last value(i) instead of the sum.  When I have the function output each value onto the spreadsheet and then sum the range I can save it in the variable but not when I just try to feed the variable the sum directly.

How do I get the variable to save the sum of all cells 1-15?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sumTotSales = sumTotSales + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(functionA(X))`.

That way, for each `i`, you are *adding* the result of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(functionA(X))` to `sumTotSales` rather than setting `sumTotSales` equal to the result of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(functionA(X))`, which is what your code is currently doing.